# Escape if statement in bash

Tags: bash

I have a line in bash:

```
if [ -e /home/somefile.xml ]; then
 mv /home/somefile.xml /home/folder.fi/somefile.xml
fi
```

now my editor is coloring `folder.fi`'s `fi` part as code. How can I escape it and does it really think it's code?

Comment: I don't understand the question but `if[` is a typo. You need a space there.

Comment: My editor is showing like i'm ending my if statement in the middle of mv command.

Comment: What editor is this? Does it help if you put the string in quotes? You also need spaces in `[-e` and `xml]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your editor's syntax highlighting is incorrect. It is safe to ignore it. The `fi` in the file name does not end the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces after and before those `[`

```
if [ -e /home/somefile.xml ]; then
 mv /home/somefile.xml /home/folder.fi/somefile.xml
fi
```

Comment: thanks, but my question is more about the if in the middle :)

Comment: there the answer would be change editor or syntax highlighting parser. Putting quotes around those paths to fix the editor makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The `.fi` is not the problem, bash doesn't interpret the dot in the middle of a path.
Instead, you're missing spaces on the first line

```
if [ -e /home/somefile.xml ]; then
  mv /home/somefile.xml /home/folder.fi/somefile.xml
fi
```

Also I'd recommand to put your file paths in double quotes like this :

```
mv "/home/somefile.xml" "/home/folder.fi/somefile.xml"
```

The editor should interpret it correctly with quotes, even if your first code is correct.

Comment: Thanks, very new to bash! :)